# When returning reactive values from a function, values don't seem to be reactive. (Error: cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character')

Tags: r, shiny, reactive-programming, reactive

I have a function that I would like to use throughout a shiny app (in the `server()` as well as other functions) to assign and return reactive and/or `reactiveValues` objects. I create a `reactiveValues` object in the function and return it, but when I try to access the values using reactive_values_object$object, it gives me the warning: `"Error in as.vector: cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'"`.

Here is a simplified version of the app:

```
source('assignvals.R')

ui <- fluidPage(

  selectInput('select', 'select', choices = c('', 'option1', 'option2')),
  htmlOutput('display')
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  x <- assignvals(input, output, session)
  
  selectval <- reactive({x$select})
  
  output$display <- renderUI({
    h4(HTML(paste('<b>you selected"</b>', selectval() )))
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

And the function:

```
assignvals <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  vals <- reactiveValues(
    select = ''
  )
  
    vals$text <- reactive(input$text)
    vals$select <- reactive({
      input$select
    })
    vals$num   <- reactive(input$num)
  
  return(vals)
}
```

It seems like there might be an issue with `input$select` not existing yet when the function is called, but despite many hours of searching and tutorial-watching, I haven't been able to wrap my head around reactivity or reactiveValues well enough to understand what the problem is.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

That's because `x$select` is reactive and you need to get it by `x$select()`.

```r
assignvals <- function(input, output, session) {
    
    vals <- reactiveValues(
        select = ''
    )
    
    vals$text <- reactive(input$text)
    vals$select <- reactive({
        input$select
    })
    vals$num   <- reactive(input$num)
    
    return(vals)
}

library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
    
    selectInput('select', 'select', choices = c('', 'option1', 'option2')),
    htmlOutput('display')
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    
    x <- assignvals(input, output, session)
    
    selectval <- reactive({x$select()})
    
    output$display <- renderUI({
        
        h4(HTML(paste('<b>you selected"</b>', selectval())))
    })
    
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

I wouldn't write the function like this. I guess you have some values with defaults, and also watch for user inputs. Then we don't need that many `reactive`. One `reactiveValues` is enough and we can use an observer to watch for the values.

```r
assignvals <- function(input, output, session) {
    
    vals <- reactiveValues(
        # give some default values
        select = '',
        text = "",
        num = NA
    )
    observe({
        vals$text <- input$text
        vals$select <- input$select
        vals$num   <- input$num 
    })
    return(vals)
}

library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
    selectInput('select', 'select', choices = c('', 'option1', 'option2')),
    textInput("text", "text", value = ""),
    numericInput("num", "num", value = 0),
    htmlOutput('display')
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    x <- assignvals(input, output, session)
    output$display <- renderUI({
        h4(HTML(paste(
            '<b>you selected"</b>', x$select, 
            " text is: ", x$text, 
            " num is ", x$num)))
    })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

Comment: Both of these worked; for anyone else looking at this the second option worked well.